# Network service area mapping over open ground

Tags: qgis, wildlife-ecology

Given a timestamped start location, a timestamped end location and a known average speed is there any way I can map everywhere someone (or something) could have possibly been between the two timestamps if they're able to travel in any absolutely direction in an area with no roads/paths etc?

The specific question here revolves around wildlife and camera traps. I have a dataset that includes details of when known individual animals were recorded by camera traps at known locations over a period of time. For example Elephant A was photographed at one location and then next seen five miles away fifteen hours later. Assuming an average speed of 3 MPH the elephant could have travelled from point A to B in a little more than an hour and a half. Being an elephant it's obviously wandered in a roundabout way (and probably stopped several times) in order to account for the extra 13+ hours between sightings.

What I'd like to do is to draw a shape covering the furthest extent in every direction that elephant could possibly have travelled in 15 hours and still made it to point B "on time". Obviously this will produce an exaggerated estimate since it's very unlikely any animal will have travelled constantly between sightings but I want to produce an overall idea of where they could have been which can (possibly) be narrowed down in future with more cameras.

Is this even vaguely possible?

I'm currently using QGIS and BigQuery's GIS tools but I'm willing to explore other solutions.

Comment: An ellipse describes the area between two sightings, with loci at the observation points and distance of the line APB determined by maximum travel distance in the time period.

Comment: @Vince That makes sense to me intuitively, but I'd like to be sure the math works out. Can you explain or link to a source that does?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to follow the suggestion by [Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince), below is a QGIS expression approach.

[image]

We need to find out (1) the center of this ellipse as point **O**, (2) semi-major axis length **x** which is the half of the total distance the elephant has moved during the time **T** (... as you see the distance `A -> B' -> B` is the same as `O -> B' -> O`). And (3) the semi-minor axis length **y** can be calculated by Pythagorean theorem (... as `A -> P -> B` is also the same as `2*x`) .

[image]

We can use QGIS expression `make_ellipse()` if we have `center point` (geometry), semi-major axis, semi-minor axis, and the azimuth (`A -> B`).

Putting them together into one expression, like:

```
make_ellipse(
  make_point(
    ($x + x(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Points', $id+1))))/2,   
    ($y + y(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Points', $id+1))))/2
  ), 
 3.0 * T / 2, 
 sqrt((3.0 * T / 2)^2 -(L / 2)^2), 
 degrees(azimuth($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('Points', $id+1)))), 
 36)
```

In this example I am assuming you have point layer (layername= `Points`) with an id field (`id`), and the recorded time interval (`T`) and the distance between the observed points (`L`), but you many require further refinement. For example `L` can be calculated by an expression below.

`distance($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('Points', $id+1)))`

(I avoided put this into the main expression for readability).

Comment: Apologies it's taken so long to acknowledge this very helpful reply, I've not been able to spend any time on this project until now. Although I'm struggling a little to figure out the implementation of this the logic makes a lot of sense and when (possibly if) I figure it out I'll be back to update with how it worked. Thankyou very much